# Mars MIPS Simulator not functioning, installation issues?

Tags: java, java-8, mips, mars-simulator, mips64

I have downloaded the Mars MIPS Simulator .jar file, and I have downloaded the java jdk file from oracle. Whenever I open the jar file, the IDE is there, but everything is greyed-out. I can't even edit the text in the window. When you select "Execute", three cut off windows appear in the box below, one titled "Text Segment", one "Data Segment", and one "Labels". I am thinking it is a failed installation, but I have no idea what else to do. Thank you for any help!

Here is a screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9ifu.png

Comment: Can you please post a screen shot? It's difficult to decide whether it's an installation issue if I don't understand what are you talking about.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/8O30Hzh.png   @jachinte

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the toolbar on the top and click paste and the edit window should work. And after you hit assemble, go to settings->Show labels window.

Comment: omg dude the show labels thing was the solution for me thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you this:

- I don't think it's an installation issue. As you said, you installed the JDK and then run the program succesfully. An installation issue would be an unexpected error because of a missing dependency, or something similar.
- As this is not a programming question, I don't think StackOverflow is the correct site. You may search in the StackExchange site for an adequate community.

However, try putting the cursor at the bottom of the cut off windows to see if you can modify the size of the container panel.

**UPDATE**

Seems like the problem is that you are not editing a file, that's why the majority of the buttons are disabled. Try creating a new file: click the first button in the toolbar, the white one. Also, the menu item "file" should give you an option to do it.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/c7NetUY.png This is what happens when I bring the window down.

Comment: @Zach I updated the question, I hope that's the problem.

Comment: No that is not the problem. It just adds a greyed out panel right under Edit/Execute named "Mips1.asm." It does not look like the IDE is functioning at all.